# Dismissing to main view controller from modal(MFMailComposeViewController)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In my app I have a main view controller and a compose view controller(which is being pushed on the main). from the compose view controller I present the `MFMailComposeViewController` like this(modal):

```
[self presentViewController:mailCont animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But when I dismiss the `mailCont` I want to go back to the main view controller.

One of the things I tried is pushing the compose view controller to the navigation stack and then using `popToRootViewController`. While running on iOS 8 it works, but on iOS 7 it crashes with an error saying it could not push a navigation controller to the navigation stack.
I've looked a lot around the internet but couldn't really find a solution that suits me the best. So any solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while presenting `MFMailComposeViewController` set the delegate of `MFMailComposeViewController` to your Compose View Controller then in implementation of delegate

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
```

you can dismiss the `MFMailComposeViewController` and also pop the compose view controller in dismiss completion block, to navigate back to Main View Controller.